# How to Update a Row in Smartsheet using a userdefined (primarykey) column?

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

Right now im using Smartsheet API 2.0 were i can update only using a RowID (basically a fixed row number) in a Smartsheet. Instead i need to update using a value from a column which i created.

Answer (score 0):

To update a cell you'll need both the row id and the column id. If you want to set a cell values for all cells created after adding a column you'll need to loop over all existing rows and update each of them.
Concerning performance and best practise, while using update rows you can send a batch of rows.